# How do I make VBA (excel) tell me the cell where my code stopped

Tags: vba, excel

I hope this is possible. I would like to know how to make excel tell me in what cell it encountered my predefined "error". For example part of the code is this:

```
Sub CheckErrors()

For Each Cel In Range("A3:A400")

    If Cel.Value = "CR" Then
        If IsEmpty(Cel.Offset(0, 6)) = True Then
        Msgbox "Add a description (name) when creating"
        End If
    End If

    If Cel.Value = "CR" Then
        If IsEmpty(Cel.Offset(0, 7)) = True Then
        Msgbox "Please choose type when creating"
        Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next
```

I would like the message boxes to also include what specific cell excel found empty. So if in column A there is CR then column G has to have a description and I would like the message box to say "Add a description (name) when creating, revise cell G3" if G3 is empty while A3 has CR in it.

Any help is appreciated. Im very new to VBA and coding, so even the most basic might be helpful!

Regards
Jim

Comment: You could add Cel.Offset(0,6).Address in the MsgBox and it will display the cell address.
The complete line would be Msgbox "Add a description (name) when creating, revise cell" & Cel.Offset(0,6).Address

Comment: Side note: you have two If statements which check whether cel.Value = "CR". Instead you could have one If statement, and have two sub statements below it. This would be easier to read and (imperceptibly) faster. Also - you should always indent each new 'section' of code. ie: within each If statement, you should indent one step further each time, so you can clearly look straight down from IF and see the END IF with nothing inbetween.

Comment: Another side note: Even though there is no visible data in the cell, IsEmpty can still return False, if there's some underlining data in it.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Thanks Ill look into that. Almost a bit too complicated for me still but I get the idea I think.

Comment: @Alex4336 Thanks Alex, as you can see below that was exactly what I needed. When it comes to the IsEmpty returning false Im not sure what underlining data is. Also what could I use instead of IsEmpty, do you have any suggestions? :-)

Comment: Sometimes a cell is not empty even though you can see no text in it, Excel is tricky that way. You could check if the cell in question's value is = "", meaning that it is blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could add inside the `MSGBOX` the property `.address`... this way:

```
Sub CheckErrors()

For Each Cel In Range("A3:A400")

    If Cel.Value = "CR" Then
        If IsEmpty(Cel.Offset(0, 6)) = True Then
        Msgbox "Add a description (name) when creating " & Cel.Offset(0, 6).address
        End If
    End If

    If Cel.Value = "CR" Then
        If IsEmpty(Cel.Offset(0, 7)) = True Then
        Msgbox "Please choose type when creating " & Cel.Offset(0, 7).address
        Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Your question is vague and unclear, please provide more info about what you really want, what you did to achieve that, what errors you have, or any other results..

**Edit**

In the comment of **Nick Dewitt** you will see what you need to  replace the `$` in the address `Replace(Cel.Offset(0, 6).address, "$", "")`

**Edit #2**

```
Sub CheckErrors()

For Each Cel In Range("A3:A400")

    If Cel.Value = "CR" Then
        If IsEmpty(Cel.Offset(0, 6)) = True Then
        Msgbox "Add a description (name) when creating " & Replace(Cel.Offset(0, 6).address, "$", "")
        End If
    End If

    If Cel.Value = "CR" Then
        If IsEmpty(Cel.Offset(0, 7)) = True Then
        Msgbox "Please choose type when creating " & Replace(Cel.Offset(0, 6).address, "$", "")
        Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Im sorry wasn't sure how to actually describe my "problem" but you were spot on. This is exactly what I was looking for. It does however show the address as $G$3 now. I suppose this has something to do with the loop. Is there a simple way of making excel drop the $ signs?

Comment: Replace(Cel.Offset(0, 6).address, "$", "") :p

Comment: Thanks Nick! Not sure where to put this unfortunately :S cant get it to work

Comment: Check the edit #2 and see what @NickDewitt say, and where to put it.

Comment: Wow, I thought I had tried that, must've entered it incorrectly. Thanks so much guys! Such quick and great help! :-)